# Shapefiles: How To Translate

Tags: file, shapes, translate

I am interested in writing my own Shapefile translator. It should be able to read the Shapefile and draw the resultant shape.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I am not interested in any sort of API or SDK. I will also be using Objective-C to do it.

Also, are there any alternatives to Shapefiles?

**UPDATE**

As an alternative to Shapefiles, use SVG maps. There are some really great free ones [here](http://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapefiles were created by ESRI and are pretty common throughout the GIS world.  There's many different ways to store GIS data though, KML, GML, GeoDatabase, Spatialite file, etc.

Here's a link to shapefile [specification](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf).  It's pretty straightforward.